# Swift Difference Between Double and Float64

Tags: swift

In Swift Programing language official documentation, It says

```
Double represents a 64-bit floating-point number.
Float represents a 32-bit floating-point number.
```

Link: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID321

Then, Why is there Float64? What is the difference between them? Or Are they same?

Comment: `Float64` is just a type alias to `Double`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The headers, found by hitting <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and searching for `Float64`, say:

```
/// A 64-bit floating point type.
public typealias Float64 = Double
/// A 32-bit floating point type.
public typealias Float32 = Float
```

and

```
Base floating point types 

    Float32         32 bit IEEE float:  1 sign bit, 8 exponent bits, 23 fraction bits
    Float64         64 bit IEEE float:  1 sign bit, 11 exponent bits, 52 fraction bits  
    Float80         80 bit MacOS float: 1 sign bit, 15 exponent bits, 1 integer bit, 63 fraction bits
    Float96         96 bit 68881 float: 1 sign bit, 15 exponent bits, 16 pad bits, 1 integer bit, 63 fraction bits

Note: These are fixed size floating point types, useful when writing a floating
      point value to disk.  If your compiler does not support a particular size 
      float, a struct is used instead.
      Use of of the NCEG types (e.g. double_t) or an ANSI C type (e.g. double) if
      you want a floating point representation that is natural for any given
      compiler, but might be a different size on different compilers.
```

As a general rule, unless you’re writing code that is dependent on binary representations, you should use the standard `Float` v `Double` names. But if you are writing something where binary compatibility is needed (e.g. writing/parsing binary `Data` to be exchanged with some other platform), then you can use the data types that bear the number of bits in the name, e.g. `Float32` vs. `Float64` vs. `Float80`.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the definiation of `Float64`

```
/// A 64-bit floating point type.
public typealias Float64 = Double

/// A 32-bit floating point type.
public typealias Float32 = Float
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, some languages default to the Float64(`f64`) type (i.e.Rust) and some languages only have the Float64 type, with no Float32  nor Double type (i.e. Fantom). The 'f' literal designates a Float64 type `num1 = 4.2f` and in this statement `num1 = 5.4d`, the `d` represents the `Decimal` class, not Double, which is equivalent to C#'s `Decimal` class or Java `BigDecimal` class.