# What are Float32 (alias of Float) and Float64 (alias of Double) for?

Tags: swift, floating-point, double

**In Swift there are 3 general floating point Types**:

- Float
- Double
- Float80

**But also there are 2 aliases**:

- Float32
- Float64

Here's a code:

```
/**/

// Float 16-bit 
Float16.exponentBitCount                 //  5
Float16.significandBitCount              //  10

// Float 32-bit
Float.exponentBitCount                   //  8
Float.significandBitCount                //  23

// Alias for Float
Float32.exponentBitCount                 //  8
Float32.significandBitCount              //  23

// Float 64-bit
Double.exponentBitCount                  //  11
Double.significandBitCount               //  52

// Alias for Double
Float64.exponentBitCount                 //  11
Float64.significandBitCount              //  52

// Extended-Precision Float
Float80.exponentBitCount                 //  15
Float80.significandBitCount              //  63

/**/
```

**Question**: What's the reason to have these 2 aliases in Swift?

What are they for?

Comment: Clarity and legacy.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070458/swift-difference-between-double-and-float64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Float64` is a type alias for `Double`, so they are the same type. The same with `Float32` and `Float`.

The names `Float` and `Double` (or `float` and `double`) are older names, used in many other languages, including C, C++, Java and C#.

[*In some languages on some (exotic or very very old) platforms, they are not even 32 and 64 bit.* But that doesn't matter for Swift.]

The newer names, `Float32`, `Float64` and `Float80` tell you the exact size of the type and are therefore a little clearer and less ambiguous. But for long time programmers, they need some getting used to. I'm not sure if Float80 is available on 64 bit platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Normal Float is 32bits so Float is simples version of Float32.
But the stoeing type of Double and Float64 in ram is very different and you can’t just compare them by their exponent and significant bits.

Comment: Double and Float64 are the same thing (type aliases). No differences in storage whatsoever. You seem to be confusing Float80 (extended precision) and Double (Float64) (double precision).